How to implement different colors for points and borders in AddPointLineAreaSeries
I want to use AddPointLineAreaSeries to achieve a point where the fill color is different from the outer border color.
This is my code.
The expected effect that he cannot achieve for me.
this.chart
        .addPointLineAreaSeries({ colors: true })
        .setPointShape(PointShape.Circle)
        .setPointSize(10)
        // .setHighlight(false)
        // .setHighlightOnHover(false)
        // .setAnimationHighlight(false)
        // .setEffect(false)
        .setPointFillStyle(
          new SolidFill({ color: ColorRGBA(229, 239, 253, 100) })
        )
        .setStrokeStyle(
          new SolidLine({
            thickness: 2,
            fillStyle: new SolidFill({ color: rgbaToObject(data.colorRgb) }),
          })
        );

What I want to achieve.
I want to use AddPointLineAreaSeries to achieve a point where the fill color is different from the outer border color.
